# Rails on Multiple Hard Drives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to configure Rails to work across multiple hard drives?  I have Ruby and Rails installed on my F: drive, but my project stored on my G: drive.  So when I try to open up the site I'm developing, I get the following error:

```
different prefix: "F:/" and "G:/"
```

about one of the stylesheets.  Is there any way to fix this, or do I need to store everything on the same drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on Windows 7 or Vista, you can use the `mklink` command to create a symbolic link from one directory to another, even if they are on different hard drives.

Comment: Thanks, that ended up fixing it!